# installing custom/default content types when site already has a theme

Tags: 2sxc

I am relatively new to DNN/developing content and the project I am currently on is already set up, it has a theme/skin and its mostly already set. They wanted me to create a module that I can't find elsewhere and was going to try to make it through. When I installed 2sxc and tried to add content I was prompted with needing to install a content package. I just want to make sure it won't alter all the other content already set up on my site because there are many pages already set up and as designed. I want to make sure I don't mess up elsewhere on the site. I just want to use this to create two drop-downs for the user to select and them display the query results based on it.

Thanks for any help/advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial install package just adds some common types / templates for you. It's only on the current portal, so it won't affect anything else.

As the prompt only appears if you have nothing installed yet, it's a safe thing to do.